# AndroidStudio/gradle - how to load Dalvik classes instead of standard JDK classes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, classloader, android-gradle-plugin

I'm fiddling with HTTPS in android and I came to the point of having to deal with java.net.InetAddress. In doing so I found out that dalvik's InetAddress class has a static method called isNumeric(host) which is not in java8 InetAddress class. As a note, the official docs do not show it, so I'm thinking I'm not even supposed to be using it.

So, say I want to use InetAddress.isNumeric in my android code, how can I make AndroidStudio/gradle load the Dalvik class and not the JDK one and avoid compilation errors?

Comment: Android Studio and Gradle do not "load the Dalvik class" or "the JDK one". The Android build process uses an `android.jar` file based upon your particular build SDK (e.g., `compileSdkVersion` in `build.gradle`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but what I mean is: how to make sure gradle load java.net.InetAddress from the Dalvik and not from the JDK? As far as I know, java classloaders load the first version of the class they find in the PATH right?

Comment: "how to make sure gradle load java.net.InetAddress from the Dalvik and not from the JDK?" -- Gradle uses neither of those, as I noted in my comment.

Comment: Since gradle loads android.jar and InetAddress is presente both in android.jar and rt.jar, which one will the jvm load first?

Comment: Gradle for Android compiles against the `android.jar` associated with your build SDK, as I have noted already. Gradle for Android does not use any `rt.jar` for the Android compilation process. The method that you are trying to use is marked with the `@hide` annotation, and therefore it does not exist in the `android.jar` copies on your development machine.

Comment: Ok. Missed the annotation there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by CommonWare, the isNumeric method is hidden through the @hide javadoc annotation and therefore not visible to the compiler.
There are ways to invoke the method but you shouldn't :).